# Помагите пожалуйста

Tags: python, for

Как В трицифровом числе N удалили вторую цифру. Когда результат умножили на 10, а к произведению добавили вторую цифру числа N, то получили число X. Найти число X, если известно значение N.

'''

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Х равен N делённый на сто умноженный на сто плюс остаток от деления N на десять умноженный на десять плюс остаток от деления N на сто делённый на десять.

Comment: Да, хорош) перебор по моему)

Comment: А что не так? Я формулу написал. На человеческом языке. )

Comment: не только формулу написал, но еще и словами объяснил=)